Is there any way to initiate a grapple from a range?
I like the idea of making a grappling character, but the party I would be making the character for needs some kind of ranged attacker.  Is there a way to combine the two concepts and either start grapples from a range or make ranged attacks that key off of my grapple checks?
I'm not just interested in immobilizing people, either.  I know spells and poisons can stop people cold from a distance, but those don't fit the flavor of grappling.

The intended way: Ranged Pin
Ranged Pin is a feat that can be found in Complete Warrior, alongside a few other feats aimed at doing melee-only special attacks from a range.  This feat allows you to make a grapple check at range to pin a target to a nearby surface with your bow or thrown weapon.
This is a trimmed-down form of grappling, though, and the escape DC is set at 15.  Plus, the opponent needs to be near a wall (though the floor might count with a permissive enough DM).  You also don't benefit from Improved Grapple's +4 bonus, which kinda sucks, though nothing prevents other benefits like Grip of Iron from applying.
That said, nothing in the feat prevents you from initiating more ranged pins once you've started one.  So, see if your DM will allow you to pin a single creature multiple times using the multiple grappling opponents rules.  This would force the creature to make that same DC 15 check multiple times in a row to escape.  Because you will likely have Rapid Shot, you will often be able to add more arrows to the pin faster than they can be broken.  Just remeber that there are limits on how many opponents can grapple a single target, and this would likely restrict how many arrows you could pin a target down with.
While your DM is being lenient, see if you can get away with using this feat with the harpoon from Dragon Compendium to double up on the immobilization.  While this shouldn't work because Ranged Pin clearly isn't supposed to deal dmage, it never outright states that it does no damage.  Thus, by the rules as written, you can pin an enemy's cloak to a wall by pinning it through their torso with a harpoon.  Definitely a bit more brutal than the writers intended.
The core rules way: Nets
The net is an exotic thrown weapon in the core rules, meaning it should be allowed at every table.  Though it's not quite a grapple in the traditional sense, since your opponent can still move, it does apply some relevant penalties and restricts movement, especially if you hold on to the trailing rope which prevents the opponent from getting away from you without a Strength check.
The main benefit here is that this weapon is very easy to slap onto an existing build.  While it is an exotic weapon, a lot of net users don't worry about getting proficiency with it because it makes touch attacks instead of regular attacks, easily offsetting the attack roll penalty for being nonproficient. As long as you have a solid base attack bonus, which you will as a grappler, you should be fine.  If needed, you could go for the Brutal Throw feat to use your high Strength and use that as an excuse to spec into more throwing weapons in general.  Maybe pick up some bolas and a harpoon to really double down on the immobilization theme.
The net does suffer from a bit of the same problem as Ranged Pin, however, namely that the net is pretty easy to get out of.  While the actual escape and burst DCs are pretty high, a reasonable slashing weapon can often break it in one hit.  It's also impossible to net very small or very large creatures.
Similar again to Ranged Pin, there can be some benefit to stacking nets.  While the penalties from the entagled condition can't stack, you can nonetheless force the opponent to escape from multiple layers of nets by throwing as many of them as you can.  Breaking the net you're actively holding will allow the oppoennt to start getting away, but there's nothing to say you can't just pick up the trailing rope on one of the other nets.
Another way to use the net would rely on a lenient DM.  Looking at the listing for the net, there is no clear advice on what happens if the net holder attempts to walk away from the entangled opponent.  However, it seems reasonably within the scope of the net's abilities and flavor to allow you to drag an opponent with you by succeeding on the same opposed Strength check that the net uses to keep the opponent from running away.  If your DM allows this, you can get on a horse and throw your net while moving.  If you move 50 feet forwards to get in range and then 50 feet back, throwing your net in the middle of your movement as per the rules, you could drag an opponent completely out of position.  This works without any feats, though you'll probably want to pick up Mounted Archery to mitigate some of the stiff penalties involved.
The cheesy way: Improved Grab
The Improved Grab ability, if you can get your hands on it (no pun intended), lets you start a grapple whenever you hit with a melee attack against a smaller opponent.  Seems tame, until you realize there's technically no range limit on it.  So, if you can find a way to make a melee attack at long range, you can follow it up with an attempt to grapple.  There are plenty of ways to do this, but here are some of the more practical:
The easiest method is to use a whip.  It's not a ranged weapon per-se, but 15 feet of range before size increases isn't bad.  There are a few published variants of it that do more stuff, too.  It's also the method least likely to test your ability to dodge thrown books, since you could feasibly imagine tying someone up with a whip to grapple them in real life.
The Bloodstorm Blade prestige class from Tome of Battle is another method.  They get an ability that lets them treat thrown weapon attacks as melee attacks.  While you can't enter this class until at least level 6, you can use nets or whips in the meantime.
The cheesiest method may be the Whirling Blade spell from Spell Compendium.  It lets you make a melee attack with a slashing weapon against everyone in a 60 foot line.  Any or all of those attacks can be followed up with a free grapple attempt if you have Improved Grab.  If you want to get really corny, you can fire this spell at longbow range with the Arcane Archer's Imbue Spell ability.
Depending on your reading of the grapple rules, your mileage may vary on what these ranged grabs may get you.  The general grapple rules include a specific step that has you move into your opponent's space, and Improved Grab lists an option to pull an opponent into your space.  Neither rule says much about how this movement happens.  The general grapple rule says it doesn't count against your movement for the round and that it provokes attacks of opportunity, and the Improved Grab rule isn't even clear on whether it always replaces the regular grapple movement or if it's just an option.
So, theoretically, this means getting an Improved Grab at a range of 1,000 feet could let you instantly travel the 1,000 feet it takes to move into your oppoent's square for free, or let you yank them straight to you.  A more level-headed reading would assume that you can't move further than your normal movement speed, and that you would at least need line-of-effect to your enemy.  A GM who is allergic to fun may rule that you're not allowed to move yourself or your foe more than your melee reach because that's clearly the distance the designers had in mind.
Whatever the GM rules on the specifics and limitations on movement here, the rules are at least clear that you still get the bonus of dealing your unarmed strike damage to a grapple target before any movement happens.  So, even if you can't (or don't want to) close in on the target of your Improved Grab attack, you can still attempt a grapple check to deal your unarmed strike damage for free.  Thus, a ranged attack that synergizes with optimizing your grapple check and unarmed strike damage.
Addendum: Cheesemaking
Following is a quick listing of the best ways to obtain Improved Grab if you want to try the cheesy grappler route.
The Spritual Totem Barbarian from Complete Champion lists an option for a Bear Totem Barbarian that grants Improved Grab at 1st level.  Since Barbarian synergizes very nicely with Bloodstorm Blade, this is probably the easiest way to do this build.  Since this version of Improved Grab does require that your opponent be smaller than you, it may be worthwhile to use a template that increases your size (Half Minotaur, while cheesy, is a favorite) and/or find a way to go into psionics to get Expansion (War Mind may be a good option, since Sweeping Strikes synergizes with everything you're trying to do).
The main benefit of this method is that you can use whatever weapon you want.  Dip into Hulking Hurler and Warhulk to grapple enemies by throwing houses at them!  Or just throw a net to entangle and grapple at the same time.
Alternatively, the Scorpion's Grasp feat from Sandstorm is a version of Improved Grab that works only for light or one-handed weapons, but in exchange it has no size restriction as long as you resolve the grapple normally.  If you're a human monk or human fighter, you can qualify for this feat at 1st level, though otherwise it may take a few levels to get rolling.
Now, while this feat covers many of the weapons most likely to be thrown, as well as the whip, it does still limit your options a bit.  Shurikens, nets, bolas, harpoons, and any other "pure" throwing weapons can't be used with this.
(Technically, the Scorpion's Grasp feat itself is actually miswritten in a way that allows it to work just fine even without Bloodstorm Blade et al;  it never requires a melee attack, just an attack with a melee weapon, which most thrown weapon attacks count as.  This definitely won't fly at a real table, but it is a pretty funny oversight.)
Do note that Druids, despite usually being great grapplers thanks to buff spells and Wildshape, are not fit for this specific kind of grappling because they lack whip proficiency, access to the Whirling Blade spell, and any version of Improved Grab that works with manufactured weapons.

Improved grab actually changes the movement portion of things: “When a creature gets a hold after an improved grab attack, it pulls the opponent into its space.” My character who used something like this—though I just increased my natural reach and used unarmed strikes—would use improved grab to pull targets to herself or regular grapple to pull herself to targets. Great fun—absurd mobility.

@KRyan I had always read that as only applying if you chose to take the special -20 to grapple with the limb that made the attack, though on second inspection it's a lot more ambiguous than I thought.  Neat.  Clearly I need to make a rope-knife using ninja with a certain catchphrase...

@HeyICanChan Fair.  I've added a section for that with a few options.  I also included mention of the enemy-pulling effect of Improved Grab.

One of the most effective remote grapple options is via Telekinesis, using the combat maneuver version. It has a range of 400' + 40' per level of the method of accessing the ability. Grappling and pinning are both specifically mentioned as options. This works using psionics, magic, or even as a ghost or other creature with innate telekinetic ability.
Additionally, Telekinesis allows one to disarm, trip, and bull rush, making it a useful crowd control power.
Adding a few levels of the Master of the Unseen Hand prestige class (Complete Warrior) adds useful options, such as multiple attacks in a round, if using levels works for your character.
